# Why is the main page of stackoverflow.com not about the site itself?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, homepage

If I go to StackOverflow.com, not logged in, I expect to see a "Explore our questions" title and a listing of questions - just like on all (?) other Stack Exchange sites.

Instead, what I see is a long page about Stack Exchange Inc. and their products.

Of course I don't mind that they plug their products to some extent, but - a person visiting the home page will not think they've reached a software Q&A site, but the company homepage. This is not good.

I realize SE inc. people don't listen to us much - especially myself as a vocal critic - but I still thought I should point this out.

Also, the "We <3 Developers" slogan on there creates some false expectations. Maybe SE inc. love developers (I'd argue that their recent actions and social media activity suggests otherwise), but we love (= the site promotes and showcases) *answers* and *questions*, not developers. It's much more meritocratic than supportive/nurturing. Whether that's good or bad is a different discussion, but it's still a [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance).

Comment: I believe that is some malicious trick to keep people log in. Once you get to this homepage  not logged in. You just don't want to log out again. Coming back to question listing from the public homepage is a nightmare that produced many Meta question.